# System Tray Item click not working on windows using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, system-tray

In Windows OS function associated with item should be executed when Item of tray is clicked.

I have created tray and menu using NW and after that added items in it. But when I run application on Windows only tray and menu item are visible function written on click is not giving any output.
I have tried following code

```
var tray = new NW. Tray({title: 'Tray Name', icon: 'icon Path'})
var menu = new nw.Menu()
menu.append({label: "label1", click: function () {//code})
menu.append({label: "label2", click: function () {//code})
tray.menu = menu
```

I have also tried using menu.click() separate for each menu but it is not working.